# Finding the mean is easy and what about maximizing the variance?

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, variance

The random variable has a normal distribution, and $$ p (- 16 <\beta < - 11 ) = p (-13  <\beta < - 8) $$  Find the variance of  $ \beta  $ for which the probability $$ p (- 11 <\beta < - 8 )  $$ is maximal. I found the mean, but I do not know how to proceed further.

Comment: sorry, variance of beta

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty clear from symmetry that the mean is $-12$ (and I presume that's what you got). Now let's think about how to maximize the probability that $-11<\beta< -8.$ Let's de-mean and flip $\beta,$ so this is the probability that a zero-mean gaussian is between $1$ and $4.$ This is given by $$ \Phi(4/\sigma) -\Phi(1/\sigma)$$ where $\Phi$ is the normal cumulative and $\sigma=\operatorname{Var}(\beta).$ We can maximize by differentiating and setting equal to zero, using the fact that $\Phi'(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}.$ This gives $$ 4e^{-\frac{16}{2\sigma^2}} = e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}}\implies \sigma^2 = \frac{15}{2\ln(4)} $$